# Flutter Camera Overlay Going Transparent

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera, ios-camera

I have made a flutter app with a customized camera feature.
Using Overlay over the camera. It looks fine in Android but in iOS it's broken, is there anything to fix this?

Here is my code snippet
https://gist.github.com/nuhin13/b8f95284ab73bb8b577a9d0cfb298cdf

Here is my Android & Ios screenshot.

[image]
[image]